# Automatically edit users input when they click off input

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems to be a simple problem - However I just can't get my head around it!
So basically what the issue is, is that when a customer enters a "Payment amount" on my website I am trying to convert their input into something like this...

**CUSTOMER INPUTS SOMETHING LIKE THIS:**
£175.98

I want it to be converted to something like this: **175.98**

Or if the customer enters 19803
I want to be able to append the decimal and comma places and remove any invalid characters like so:
19,803.00

I have searched and searched the internet for about 2 days and can't find anything like this!

Sorry I haven't provided any code but I figured if i can't find anything like this I'm sure that others will have the same issue.

Form I am using:

```
<form action="https://myaccount.mysite.com/s/customer/payment/new-payment/action.do" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pamt" id="payment_amount" />
    <input type="submit" value="Continue to PayPal" />
</form>
```

Comment: 1: https://www.google.com/search?q=input+event, 2: https://www.google.com/search?q=format+currency+javascript

Comment: To be honest, if you couldn't find the `blur` event with 2 days of searching, you need to stop using bing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out numeral.js. I have used it for similar formatting tasks in the past.

http://numeraljs.com/

For example:

```
var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0.00');
```

So, then you could use the onblur event to change the value to what you would like it to be:

```
<form action="https://myaccount.mysite.com/s/customer/payment/new-payment/action.do" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pamt" id="payment_amount" onblur="try{this.value = numeral(this.value).format('0,0.00') }catch(e){};" />
    <input type="submit" value="Continue to PayPal" />
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

It appears there is a bug in the following version of numeral.js

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

However, I had full success using the version titled numeral.js that can be downloaded here:

https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/zipball/master

Comment: How would I implement this for when a user clicks off the input rather than `onkeyup`

Comment: I just edited my answer. You just use the onblur event. However, try to make sure first that the form cannot be submitted without that event occurring or you will have an animal in the machine.

Comment: When a $ or £ is inserted the the value sets to 0.00? e.g. £256.76 = 0.00

Comment: No, it will take £256.76  and turn it into 256.76. The zeros are part of the formatting code.

Comment: Instead of that value is their a way to change it to just removing the $ £ but maintaining the value?

Comment: Yes, that is what it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90927/discussion-between-joshua-dannemann-and-rra-webteam).

Comment: [See my JSFiddle for an example of what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/53xmh5qk/1/)

Comment: Strange. It does not do that in any of the browsers I tested it in. I think JS Fiddle breaks it.

Comment: It's happening on our live site

Comment: Okay, that is weird. The minified version you are using has a bug in it. The un-minified version I used here https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/zipball/master works. I will edit my answer.